# Rebinding dynamic dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a drop down list populated with my database data when displaying user data. The problem is that when validation fails and post to the controller the drop down values are lost and I get an error. I have tried using tempdata but I get the same problem when validation fails the second time. Is there a better way to store values or maintain state without fetching everything back from the database.

Ta!

Comment: no,  there isn't a clean way to store a drop down list on the view,  your best option will be to requery

Comment: Use ajax to fill the dropdown on page load.

Comment: What kind of information you will be having in dropdownlist? How often the items in dropdownlist will change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use TempData you have to do it like this:

```
get method
{
  ....
  TempData["yourDDLItems"] = items;
  TempData.Keep();
}

post method
{
  TempData.Keep();
}
```

Comment: This works great. I basically wanted temp storage for the data. Another approuch is to store dropdown data in a hidden field.